# How to show html table with ajax from jsonresult on my view

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello everybody I can't append a table on my view... my jsonresult send the data ok but I have problem to showing on my table... it show the data for 1 milisecond and then looks like the page refresh and show nothing and I don't know why...

**On my controller**

```
   [HttpGet] 
    public JsonResult GenerarDetalleInventariobyU(Guid id)
    {
      var result = (from item in bienasignado.GetAll()
                      where item.Ubicacion == id
                      select new
                      {
                          Descripcion = item.Bien.Descripcion,
                          Empleado = item.IdEmpleado

                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**On my View**

```
function getDetail() {
    var selectedU = $("#UnidadesAdministrativas").val();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GenerarDetalleInventariobyU", "Inventario")',
        data: { "id": selectedU },
        success: function (data) {
            var tr;
            //Append each row to html table
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Descripcion + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Empleado + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);

            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: How are you calling the `getDetail()` function? Best guess is its triggered from a link of button and you have not cancelled the default action

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Also append the dynamic table that you created in your success function as a child element to any existing element on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (probably easier one) is,

1. make your action to return PartialView that way, you can craft your
   view in a .cshtml page. Instead of returning `JsonResult`, modify it
   to return `PartialView`.
2. onSuccess of your $.ajax call, bind this partial view to any form element like `$('#divResults').html(data)` where 
   divResults is id of a div (`<div id='divResults'></div>`) element and `data` is the return value from your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are handling success method in incorrect way.

```
success: function (data) {
            var tr;
            //Append each row to html table
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr>'); // remove slash from here
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Descripcion + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Empleado + "</td>");
                tr.append("<tr/>"); // close it here.
                $('table').append(tr);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in your success function

```
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('table').append(
                $('<tr>')
                    .append($('<td>').append(item.Descripcion))
                    .append($('<td>').append(item.Empleado))
            );
            });
```